# Diagonal element should be equal to sum of the non diagonal element

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a requirement where I need to sum the elements each row and then assign the sum to the diagonal element.

For example a 2D array of size [4][4], the diagonal element should be the sum of the non diagonal element.

```
R11= R12 + R13 + R14
R22= R21 + R23 + R24
R33= R31 + R32 + R34
R44= R41 + R42 + R43
```

Can someone please help on how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the problem ? If so please post the code and specific errors you are encountering. This community will not help if you state a problem and ask for us to write the code.

Comment: Sounds like a simple nested loop to me. Where did you struggle with it specifically?

Answer (score 1):

As you described, the 2D array with 16 elements will look like this:

`int[][] matrix = new int[4][4]`

Values inside this array are unimportant, but the real thrust of your question seems to be the iterative solution. While I will not be writing all your code for you, perhaps you could think of the problem like this:

Maintain an index for iterating over the array, we'll call this `column`, additionally, we'll have another index for iterating called `row` and for each row of the array we will need to store a value equal to the sum of the other 3 elements. On the first iteration, we could say the sum of these elements would be stored at the index of `column`, `row` and then increment each variable by one before summing the 3 non-diagonal elements of the next row.

Comment: Thanks guys, i was able to get a solution to the above.